# how to fix '[Errno 111] Connection refused' error in python (telegram-bot)?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I was coding to learn how to create a telegram-bot with python .

and after the last line I pressed enter this error showed up :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in 
_send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in 
_send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1392, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 936, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in 
create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in 
create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in 
_call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in 
https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection 
refused>
```

I tried to use http instead of https but it didn't work.

This is the code I tried:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
TOKEN = 'token'
URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/'.format(TOKEN)
cmd = 'getme'
resp = urlopen(URL + cmd)
```

I expect no errors!

Comment: That looks like a problem on the remote end; the socket connection was refused before you ever had a chance to send your request to the API.

Comment: Yes . actually i think it is because of the restrictions of my country . now I think I have to change my IP address . but in Linux I did not found any VPN that can cover whole device they just cover my browser .

Comment: @PooyaRabiei check [this](https://sweetcode.io/routing-all-traffic-through-a-vpn-gateway-on-linux/)